# Load UIViewController twice in navigation stack

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` (say A). On the click of a button in the `UIViewController`(A), I load a `UIWebView`. On click of a component in the `UIWebView`, I need to push the `UIViewController`(A) once again. I know, that conceptually its not the right thing to do. What are the alternatives here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is, do you want a new instance of the UIViewController, or you just want to update the first UIViewController?
For the first option, you have to create a new instance of UIViewController and push it.
For the second option, you have to pop the UIWebView controller and send a message to the first UIViewController to update itself, or generate a notification that the UIViewController listens to in order to update itself.

Comment: I am creating a new instance. But the problem is that, when I am debugging, the control enters `initWithNibName` and exits but not `viewDidLoad` of Class A

Answer (score 0):

You cannot push the same `UIViewController` twice on the navigation stack. But you could create a new instance of class A and push that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have multiple actions for the same button. In my case I have given 2 IBActions for same button.